# Generating a shared access Signature for a block blob in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have some code that is suppose to give me a Shared access signature on a pdf in a azure blob.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("BlobEndpoint=<url>;AccountKey=<accountKey>");

            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("products");

            BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();
            containerPermissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off;

            container.SetPermissions(containerPermissions);

            containerPermissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Add("mypolicy", new SharedAccessPolicy()
            {
                SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(1),
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Read | SharedAccessPermissions.Write
            });

            string sas = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessPolicy(), "mypolicy");

            CloudBlobClient sasBlobClient = new CloudBlobClient(storageAccount.BlobEndpoint, new StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature(sas));

            CloudBlob blob = sasBlobClient.GetBlobReference("products/virtual/computer/brochure.pdf");

            Console.WriteLine(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sas);

        }
    }
```

When I run the code and paste the URL into the browser I get the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
   <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
   <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:05c9cfc0-d7fd-4352-9b21-9e273efdc09f Time:2014-02-05T13:36:05.6126781Z</Message>
   <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was /portalvhdsv53d88583slg1/products mypolicy</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

All i want is to generate the URL that will give me access to the pdf for a period of time for an item in the blob storage. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and remove the account key. Also, I would recommend regenerating account key.

Comment: The key there was not the actual key, it was a fake. Why regenerate the key?

Comment: I thought it was an actual key thus the comment. Regenerate because somebody could look at revision history and use they. The issue is moot considering the key is not real. Sorry for pressing the panic button :)

Comment: lol no problem, always good too keep in mind for future posts

Comment: First, get rid of the SharedAccessStartTime.  Second, what is the URL being returned?  I am not sure where "portalvhdsv53d88583slg1" is coming from.

Comment: The "portalvhdsv53d88583slg1" is the dummy name of the storage account. The URL that is being returned looks something like this: `https://portalvhdsv53d88583slg1.blob.core.windows.net/productmarket/virtual%2Fcomputer%2Fbrochure.pdf?sr=b&sv=2012-02-12&si=IGBlob&sig=Ch%2F9JcbmOkBASKKGWiU8s9qsAf8cGkGgFLgIGi5HRtE%3D`

Comment: Just wondering, did changing the start time fix the issue for you?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, the permission policy will be valid after 1 second from the creation.

```
SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(1),
SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
```

So you have to wait at least 1 second after the creation before to acces.

Try this insetead:

```
SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow(),
SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
```

In this case the policy is immediatly active